# Gtk-WARNING: Theme parsing error:

Tags: cinnamon

i've been experiencing several issues with my cinnamon in Linux Mint 17.3. I've been checking the `syslog` after every boot and have noticed a particular error every single time. This issue maybe be related to [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/313466/143031) for which I haven't found a solution to yet.

This is the output from `syslog`:

```
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.57608s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:77:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.57757s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:77:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58041s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:748:25: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58123s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:749:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58159s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:750:26: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58194s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:751:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58228s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:756:25: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58295s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:757:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58312s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:758:26: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58429s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:759:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58769s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:764:25: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58789s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:765:24: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58798s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:766:26: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58806s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:767:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58834s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:843:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58842s: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:843:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.58908s: Theme parsing error: unity.css:15:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Oct  6 13:04:33 arden-PC cinnamon-session[2738]: Gtk-WARNING: t+1566.59222s: Theme parsing error: unity.css:22:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```